# Name columns created in for-loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I'm inserting new columns with a for-loop in same amount as already existing columns in pandas dataframe (making columns x2 as many). I get the correct number of new columns with below loop, but they are named 1 through 3 (number of primary columns)

However, I want a word in front of these numbers. e.g. "hi"

```
for i in range(1,len(df.columns)+1):
    df[i] =  0
    print(i)
```

I get:

| Primary Col 1 | Primary Col 2 | Primary Col 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | a | a | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| a | a | a | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I want:

| Primary Col 1 | Primary Col 2 | Primary Col 3 | hi1 | hi2 | hi3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | a | a | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| a | a | a | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Anyone wish to help me?

Comment: `df['hi' + str(i)] = 0`?

Comment: Thanks! @BigBen
I was wondering why this wasn't working, but I was missing the "str."
New to loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @BigBen commented, you can directly concatenate a string in the for loop:

```
for i in range(1,len(df.columns)+1):
    df['hi' + str(i)] =  0
    print(i)
```

You might also concatenate variables or use f-strings e.g.

```
foo = "Hi"
for i in range(1,len(df.columns)+1):
    df[foo + str(i)] =  0
    print(i)
```

With f-strings:

```
foo = "Again"
for i in range(1,len(df.columns)+1):
    df[f'Hi_{foo}'+ str(i)] =  0
    print(i)
```

Comment: Edited, was missing cast to string for the counter

Comment: Thanks, Adam. I was missing "str"-command when trying

Answer (score 0):

The answer is stated by @BigBen above.
Thanks!

```
for i in range(1,len(df.columns)+1):
    df['hi' + str(i)] = 0
    print(i)
```